# Setting up a global variable to count recursions

Tags: java, recursion, global-variables

```
public class collatzpow {

    public static int collatz(int n) {

        StdOut.print( n + " ");
        if (n == 1) return 0;
        if (n% 2 == 0) return collatz(n/2);
        else return collatz(3*n + 1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            StdOut.println(collatz(7));
    }
}
```

I want to set up a global variable to count the number of time the program calls the recursion. I know with the number 7 it calls it 17 times.

I've been told it is very easy, but I'm struggling a bit with it.

Comment: Not sure what StdOut is. In java, you are normally using System.out.In order to have such a global variable, just declare it within your class, like `class Whatever { static int recursionCounter = 0; ...` and then you can increase and print that variable from your methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a static int variable in the class scope and increment each time the method is called.

```
public class collatzpow {

public static int count = 0;
public static PrintStream StdOut = System.out;

public static int collatz(int n) {
    ++count;
    StdOut.print(n + " ");
    if (n == 1) return 0;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return collatz(n / 2);
    else return collatz(3 * n + 1);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    StdOut.println(collatz(7));
    System.out.println(count);
}
  }
```